# Why are 2D points represented with a matrix of {x, y, 1} and 2D vectors represented with a matrix of {x, y, 0}?

Tags: vector, matrix, 3d, point

I'm having trouble understanding this conceptually. What is the difference between points and vectors that requires a 1 in the 3rd place for a point and a 0 in the 3rd place for a vector?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

The form (x, y, 1) is the representation of a point in [homogeneous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). This allows a point to rotated and translated just by multiplying with a transformation matrix. For 3D this is very important for computer graphics.
One reason for representing a vector as (x, y, 0) is that a vector added to a point has to give a point, or equivalently the difference between two points is a vector. You can find lots of resources by googling for "homogeneous coordinates", e.g. [this one from MIT](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/geometry/homo-coor.html)

Answer (score 0):

With homogeneous coordinates, the magnitude does not matter. The following values represent the same point

```
{ x, y, 1 }
{ 2x, 2y, 2 }
```

To get the coordinates from `{a, b, c}` you do

`(x,y) = (a/c, b/c)`.

Now to represent a direction you use a degenerate point (with `c=0`) such that it does not have `x,y` coordinates.

To get the direction vector from `{a, b, 0}` you normalize the vector with

`(ux,uy) = (a/√(a^2+b^2), b/√(a^2+b^2) )`

So by convention, when the homogeneous scalar `c` is non-zero the values represent coordinates and when `c` is zero they represent direction.

This convention helps defining points along a line, given a line origin `r={rx,ry,1}` and a unit direction `u={ux,uy,0}` along a distance `t` the point is

```
q = r + u*t = (rx,ry,1) + (ux,uy,0)*t = (rx+ux*t, ry+uy*t, 1)
```

which has coordinates `(qx,qy) = (rx+ux*t, ry+uy*t)`. Now if the vector had a value in the 3rd coordinate then point `q` would not be calculated correctly.

<sub>**Note:**</sub> this applies for 2D as well as for 3D (with 4 values).